# Chrome webview tag call getZoom function but receive "is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I'm currently writing a Chrome App that uses a webview tag.

I want to get the current zoom factor of the webview element, so I write down this:

```
var zoom = 1.0;
var webview = document.querySelector('webview');
webview.getZoom(function(zoomFactor){zoom = zoomFactor;});
```

When I reload the app, I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: webview.getZoom is not a function`

However, when I write the third line in console, I get the right value of zoom.

[Here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#method-getZoom) is the link to the webview docs.

Please help me.

Comment: I guess it hasn't yet initialized. Try waiting using setTimeout or some kind of on-loaded event.

Comment: @wOxxOm That IS the cause. Thank you so much.